# Not able to add Context

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am not able to make Toast, it shows error in context

[image: Please find screenshot]

Comment: I'm not much familiar with Kotlin but in JAVA you must pass 'context' as a parameter from the parent class to set an adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way to do this

1. `view?.context`

The above code will return the context.

2. you can pass the **context** in **constructor** while creating Instance from Activity/Fragment.

   `class onAdapterItemClickLister(private val mContext: Context?)`

Answer (score 0):

use this to get `context`

```
view.root.context
```